# modifying a jquery auto-suggest script to work with python

Tags: jquery, python, autosuggest

I am having trouble modifying an auto suggest jquery script I found I am trying to add temporarily to a web app I am making that, in this specific example will be selecting english words from a modified wordnet dictionary.

Here is the demo:

```
http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#demo
```

Now here is the code that is ment to be modified and contains all the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.visualSearch = VS.init({
      container  : $('#search_box_container'),
      query      : 'country: "South Africa" account: 5-samuel "U.S. State": California',
      // query      : '',
      unquotable : [
        'text',
        'account',
        'filter',
        'access'
      ],
      callbacks  : {
        search : function(query, searchCollection) {
          var $query = $('#search_query');
          $query.stop().animate({opacity : 1}, {duration: 300, queue: false});
          $query.html('<span class="raquo">&raquo;</span> You searched for: <b>' + searchCollection.serialize() + '</b>');
          clearTimeout(window.queryHideDelay);
          window.queryHideDelay = setTimeout(function() {
            $query.animate({
              opacity : 0
            }, {
              duration: 1000,
              queue: false
            });
          }, 2000);
        },
        valueMatches : function(category, searchTerm, callback) {
          switch (category) {
          case 'account':
              callback([
                { value: '1-amanda', label: 'Amanda' },
                { value: '2-aron',   label: 'Aron' },
                { value: '3-eric',   label: 'Eric' },
                { value: '4-jeremy', label: 'Jeremy' },
                { value: '5-samuel', label: 'Samuel' },
                { value: '6-scott',  label: 'Scott' }
              ]);
              break;
            case 'filter':
              callback(['published', 'unpublished', 'draft']);
              break;
            case 'access':
              callback(['public', 'private', 'protected']);
              break;
            case 'title':
              callback([
                'Pentagon Papers',
                'CoffeeScript Manual',
                'Laboratory for Object Oriented Thinking',
                'A Repository Grows in Brooklyn'
              ]);
              break;
            case 'city':
              callback([
                'Cleveland',
                'New York City',
                'Brooklyn',
                'Manhattan',
                'Queens',
                'The Bronx',
                'Staten Island',
                'San Francisco',
                'Los Angeles',
                'Seattle',
                'London',
                'Portland',
                'Chicago',
                'Boston'
              ])
              break;
            case 'U.S. State':
              callback([
                "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California",
                "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida",
                "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois",
                "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana",
                "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota",
                "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada",
                "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina",
                "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania",
                "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee",
                "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Virgin Islands",
                "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"
              ]);
              break
            case 'country':
              callback([
                "China", "India", "United States", "Indonesia", "Brazil",
                "Pakistan", "Bangladesh", "Nigeria", "Russia", "Japan",
                "Mexico", "Philippines", "Vietnam", "Ethiopia", "Egypt",
                "Germany", "Turkey", "Iran", "Thailand", "D. R. of Congo",
                "France", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Myanmar", "South Africa",
                "South Korea", "Colombia", "Ukraine", "Spain", "Tanzania",
                "Sudan", "Kenya", "Argentina", "Poland", "Algeria",
                "Canada", "Uganda", "Morocco", "Iraq", "Nepal",
                "Peru", "Afghanistan", "Venezuela", "Malaysia", "Uzbekistan",
                "Saudi Arabia", "Ghana", "Yemen", "North Korea", "Mozambique",
                "Taiwan", "Syria", "Ivory Coast", "Australia", "Romania",
                "Sri Lanka", "Madagascar", "Cameroon", "Angola", "Chile",
                "Netherlands", "Burkina Faso", "Niger", "Kazakhstan", "Malawi",
                "Cambodia", "Guatemala", "Ecuador", "Mali", "Zambia",
                "Senegal", "Zimbabwe", "Chad", "Cuba", "Greece",
                "Portugal", "Belgium", "Czech Republic", "Tunisia", "Guinea",
                "Rwanda", "Dominican Republic", "Haiti", "Bolivia", "Hungary",
                "Belarus", "Somalia", "Sweden", "Benin", "Azerbaijan",
                "Burundi", "Austria", "Honduras", "Switzerland", "Bulgaria",
                "Serbia", "Israel", "Tajikistan", "Hong Kong", "Papua New Guinea",
                "Togo", "Libya", "Jordan", "Paraguay", "Laos",
                "El Salvador", "Sierra Leone", "Nicaragua", "Kyrgyzstan", "Denmark",
                "Slovakia", "Finland", "Eritrea", "Turkmenistan"
              ], {preserveOrder: true});
              break;
          }
        },
        facetMatches : function(callback) {
          callback([
            'account', 'filter', 'access', 'title',
            { label: 'city',    category: 'location' },
            { label: 'address', category: 'location' },
            { label: 'country', category: 'location' },
            { label: 'U.S. State', category: 'location' },
          ]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now I am trying to modify it to instead of getting all the data from the jquery script, I want to get the data from a python script on the same server, and use that data instead (because I couldn't ever add all the data to the one file, since the data-set is massive). But what I basically am trying to do is, pretty much two things.

The first being at the end, where it says "facetMatches" it has a list of terms (like account, filter, etc...) and terms in brackets. I would like to keep the terms in brackets but I want the other terms to be instead of "'account', 'filter', 'access', 'title'," I would like it to be a list of thousands of words, accessed from a python script, instead of just written in.

The second being, in the 'ValueaMatches' Section, where the "Switch case" already exists, with a list of outputs for each word, I want each word to have a list of results, once again from a python script. I would also like to have the 4 words in the brackets of the facetMatches still have individual cases. I know that could easyily be done with an if statement but I do not know how to get the data from a python script.

Also, for the python scripts, what would I have in each script to output the right data? I already have functions that print out everything I need, just not in the format that I would probably need.

Comment: [Python can spit data out in a JSON Encoded Format](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/json/)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the server for the list of data in json format. This you can do by making a python list and transforming it into json format using the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. Depending on your version of python this module will be called `simple_json`, but in recent versions of python it is just `json`.

In your javascript you'd fire a `jQuery.ajax()` call to the server and read the response into your list variable.

Comment: so would I put jQuery.ajax() inside the callback(...Here...)?

Comment: I could not find the implementation of `callback` in this code, so I cannot not judge what it is supposed to do. I think the ajax call should be inside the valueMatches.